# xmllint not parsing attributes with --stream

Tags: xml, validation, xmllint

I'm using xmllint on OS X to try to validate an XML file against an XSD.

The sample XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<volume_entries>
    <volume_entry>
        <period>2011-08-01</period>
        <volume units="lb">15.23</volume>
        <uuid>64091d84-2687-11dd-a4e9-daf105bfb8c2</uuid>
        <serial_ident>31515-1251512</serial_ident>
        <supplier>Supplier A</supplier>
        <category type="wild_farmed">Wild farmed A</category>
        <category type="procurement">Procurement option A</category>
        <category type="latin_name">latin_name A</category>
        <category type="wild_farmed">WILD CAUGHT</category>
    </volume_entry>
</volume_entries>
```

And the sample XSD is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:element name="volume_entries">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="volume_entry"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="volume_entry">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="period"/>
        <xs:element ref="volume"/>
        <xs:element ref="uuid"/>
        <xs:element ref="serial_ident"/>
        <xs:element ref="supplier"/>
        <xs:element ref="category"/>
        <xs:element ref="category"/>
        <xs:element ref="category"/>
        <xs:element ref="category"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="period" type="xs:date"/>
  <xs:element name="volume">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>Volumes are decimals with a string 'unit' attribute that can be one of: kg - kilograms, lb - pounds, t - metric tonne, LT - long ton (UK), ST - short ton (US).</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base="xs:decimal">
          <xs:attribute name="units" use="required">
            <xs:simpleType>
              <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:enumeration value="kg"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="lb"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="t"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="LT"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="ST"/>
              </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
          </xs:attribute>
        </xs:extension>
      </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="uuid" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="serial_ident" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="supplier" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="category">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>Category is a string with a string 'type' attribute that can be one of 'procurement', 'latin_name', 'harvest_country' or 'wild_farmed'</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base="xs:string">
          <xs:attribute name="type" use="required">
            <xs:simpleType>
              <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:enumeration value="procurement"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="latin_name"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="harvest_country"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="wild_farmed"/>                
              </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
          </xs:attribute>
        </xs:extension>
      </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

If I try to validate by parsing the whole document, eg:

```
$ xmllint --schema /Users/mezza9/sample.xsd /Users/mezza9/sample.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<volume_entries>
<volume_entry>
<period>2011-08-01</period>
<volume units="lb">15.23</volume>
<uuid>64091d84-2687-11dd-a4e9-daf105bfb8c2</uuid>
<serial_ident>31515-1251512</serial_ident>
<supplier>Supplier A</supplier>
<category type="wild_farmed">Wild farmed A</category>
<category type="procurement">Procurement option A</category>
<category type="latin_name">latin_name A</category>
<category type="wild_farmed">WILD CAUGHT</category>
</volume_entry>
</volume_entries>
/Users/mezza9/sample.xml validates
```

Then the file validates.

If, however, I use the streaming API I get validation failure?!

```
$ xmllint --stream --schema /Users/mezza9/sample.xsd /Users/mezza9/sample.xml 
/Users/mezza9/sample.xml:5: Schemas validity error : Element 'volume', attribute 'units': [facet 'enumeration'] The value '' is not an element of the set {'kg', 'lb', 't', 'LT', 'ST'}.
/Users/mezza9/sample.xml:5: Schemas validity error : Element 'volume', attribute 'units': '' is not a valid value of the local atomic type.
/Users/mezza9/sample.xml:9: Schemas validity error : Element 'category', attribute 'type': [facet 'enumeration'] The value '' is not an element of the set {'procurement', 'latin_name', 'harvest_country', 'wild_farmed'}.
/Users/mezza9/sample.xml:9: Schemas validity error : Element 'category', attribute 'type': '' is not a valid value of the local atomic type.
/Users/mezza9/sample.xml:10: Schemas validity error : Element 'category', attribute 'type': [facet 'enumeration'] The value '' is not an element of the set {'procurement', 'latin_name', 'harvest_country', 'wild_farmed'}.
/Users/mezza9/sample.xml:10: Schemas validity error : Element 'category', attribute 'type': '' is not a valid value of the local atomic type.
/Users/mezza9/sample.xml:11: Schemas validity error : Element 'category', attribute 'type': [facet 'enumeration'] The value '' is not an element of the set {'procurement', 'latin_name', 'harvest_country', 'wild_farmed'}.
/Users/mezza9/sample.xml:11: Schemas validity error : Element 'category', attribute 'type': '' is not a valid value of the local atomic type.
/Users/mezza9/sample.xml:12: Schemas validity error : Element 'category', attribute 'type': [facet 'enumeration'] The value '' is not an element of the set {'procurement', 'latin_name', 'harvest_country', 'wild_farmed'}.
/Users/mezza9/sample.xml:12: Schemas validity error : Element 'category', attribute 'type': '' is not a valid value of the local atomic type.
/Users/mezza9/sample.xml fails to validate
```

I'm using the current system version of xmllint:

```
$ xmllint --version
xmllint: using libxml version 20904
   compiled with: Threads Tree Output Push Reader Patterns Writer SAXv1 FTP HTTP DTDValid HTML Legacy C14N Catalog XPath XPointer XInclude ICU ISO8859X Unicode Regexps Automata Expr Schemas Schematron Modules Debug Zlib 
$ which xmllint
/usr/bin/xmllint
```

Any advice would be much appreciated.